# How to update marker popup content & icon for leaflet cluster plugin without closing popup

Tags: leaflet, markers

I have integrated leaflet cluster for maps. But in my scenario data dynamically comes from mqtt, So markers count, their icon & popup content is changed all the times when new data came.

This is code integrated which works fine

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.cluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
   initializeMap(); 
   // Some methd for getting past data on page initiation
   callback().subscribe(mapdata => {
      this.locations = mapdata;
      renderPoints();
   });

   // Some methd for getting data from mqtt when comes
   mqttcallback().subscribe(mapdata => {
      this.locations = mapdata;
      renderPoints();
   });

} 



initializeMap() {
    const self = this;
    this.map = L.map('map').setView(L.latLng(LAT, LON), 5);
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(this.map);
  }


renderPoints () {
    let myIcon =  L.icon( { iconUrl: this.defaultIcon, shadowUrl: this.defaultIcon } );
    this.cluster.clearLayers();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
      const a = this.locations[i];
      const title = a.location;
      if ( a.icon !== null ) {
        myIcon =  L.icon( { iconUrl: a.icon, shadowUrl: a.icon } );
      }
      const marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat, a.lng), {icon: myIcon, title: title });
      let info = '';
      info += '<div style="margin-bottom: -12px;"><div>' + title;
      if (typeof a.address !== 'undefined') {
        info += ('</div>' + a.address);
      }

      info += '</div></br>';
      if ( a.items ) {
        for (let j = 0; j < a.items.length; j++ ) {
          if ( a.items[j].name ) {
            info +='<div>';
            info += '<strong>' + a.items[j].name + ': </strong>' + a.items[j].time + '<br/>';
            info+='</div>';
          }
        }
      }
      marker.bindPopup(L.popup({maxHeight: 300}).setContent(info));
      this.cluster.addLayer(marker);
    }

    this.map.addLayer(this.cluster);
  }
```

My issue is that when new data comes, renderPoints method comes with updated locations. Then map is redrawn by current code, So all open popup closed down. As data is frequently comes, I am unable to correctly analyse popup content due to popup close down.

I searched for some update only functionality on other questions, but solutions look like will regenerate marker which failed my case.

How to update marker popup content & icon for leaflet cluster plugin without closing popup?